# por que error al crear tabla de MySQL

Tags: mysql

tengo el siguiente script:

```
  CREATE TABLE test.sdfs(
  `date` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp()
)
```

me arroja el error siguiente:

**#1067 - Invalid default value for 'date'**

si existe algun otro error hagame saber pues **NO** debo cambiar los valores default

Comment: que versión de MySQL usas? quizás la 5.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno después de unas pruebas, he encontrado que:

Con la versión 5.5 o inferior del servidor de MySQL indicar que un campo `DATETIME` fallará al asignarle como valor por *default* un `current_timestamp()`

Mientras que si le asignas que el tipo de columna sea `TIMESTAMP` funcionará correctamente

- Aquí un [enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r82WWWbzGe5HB4geYXKeFG/0) donde funciona
- Aquí un [enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kefgFw3QE417zPbqCzMHTL/0) con la misma versión del server pero usando `DATETIME` y mostrando el fallo indicado

De la versión 5.6 en adelante dicha asignación funcionará; es decir lo siguiente sera válido

```
date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

o también

```
date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
```

Este es el [enlace](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2e4f120c5a641c323b7bfd6e1827f4a6) al ejemplo

> Entonces si usas MySQL 5.5 y no puedes actualizar cambia `DATETIME` en
>   el tipo de columna por `TIMESTAMP` o en caso contrario usa una versión
>   mas reciente de dicho servidor de bases de datos